# How Can I get the latest value for each name In where clause?

Tags: mysql, group-by

How I can get only the latest value for each name.

```
SQL="SELECT name,Myvalue,theDate from Mytable where name in ('name1','name2','name3')";
```

so the result in the case will be 3 records only.
Primery Key:AutoInc.
theDate:date of the value.

Comment: so how you know what is the latest value of each name? I dont see any date field or autonumeric ID

Comment: Do you have primary key in the table?  Of course, you can use `LIMIT 3`

Comment: There is a field date in the table too. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Also, `table`  (and `date`) is a reserved keyword

Comment: `SELECT name, MIN(value) from table where name in ('name1','name2','name3') GROUP BY name HAVING date = MAX(date)`

Comment: Primary key is just AutoInc ID.

Comment: select name, value from table order by id desc limit 3

Comment: @HannoBinder why `MIN(Value)` ?

Comment: hanno's answer makes zero sense..

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Valid question. Does MySQL accept non-aggregate columns in the projection which are not grouped by?

Comment: @Pamblam's answer makes no sense. The OP wants "latest value *for each name*". No one requested "the three records with the highest ID values".

Comment: `SELECT name, MIN(value), theDate from table where name in ('name1','name2','name3') GROUP BY name HAVING theDate = MAX(theDate)`

Comment: @HannoBinder the id column is auto inc, meaning the highest ids will be the latest. the value has nothing to do with when it was inserted.

Comment: @HannoBinder I can't understand why MIN(value) ?

Comment: hanno is just trolling i think..

Comment: @Pamblam Did you see that there's a date `theDate` associated with each value?

Comment: @mo.dhouibi `MAX` should work just as well. It's just there to get a single value even if multiple different values have the same `theDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variables to create a `row_number` in mysql.

Because data is order `by DATE DESC` bringing the rows with `rownum = 1` will return the latest of each name

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94a52/9)**

**TEST DATA**

```
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`name`, `Myvalue`, `theDate`)
VALUES
    ('name1', 1, '2016/01/10'),
    ('name1', 7, '2016/01/11'),
    ('name1', 6, '2016/01/12'),  <-- latest
    ('name2', 2, '2016/01/03'),  <-- latest
    ('name2', 5, '2016/01/02'),
    ('name2', 3, '2016/01/01'),
    ('name3', 30, '2016/01/05'),
    ('name3', 12, '2016/01/06'),
    ('name3', 33, '2016/01/07')  <-- latest
;
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT name,
       Myvalue,
       theDate
FROM
    (  
        SELECT name,
               Myvalue,
               theDate,
               (@rownum := if(@name = name,
                              @rownum + 1,  -- increase rownum 
                              if (@name := name, -- reset counter
                                  1,
                                  1)
                             )
                ) rownum
        FROM ForgeRock 
        CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 1, @name := '') params  -- initialize the variables
        WHERE name in ('name1','name2','name3')
        ORDER BY name, theDate desc
     ) T
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY name
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  name | Myvalue |                   theDate |
|-------|---------|---------------------------|
| name1 |       6 | January, 12 2016 00:00:00 |
| name2 |       2 | January, 03 2016 00:00:00 |
| name3 |      33 | January, 07 2016 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Sorry, but that must be the most complicated solution possible while a simple group by/having is all that's needed.

Comment: @HannoBinder You can always post your own answer, But I cant see your solution of `group by` working so I post my solution. I can understand if you dont like it, but this solve the problem so I will have to leave it here until OP found a solution.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Your solution working quickly but is there an easy way to add a new field? Example: Location, the result will show something like this:

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 
So we add and location IN(location1,location2) and the result:
Location1 |name1|myval
Location1|name2|myval
location1|name3|myval
location2|name1|myval
location2|name2|myval
location2|name3|myval
Where myval is always the latest according to theDate
Thank you

Comment: @mo.dhouibi sorry I dont understand, but if you want modify your question I suggest you create a new one. Where you can format the data properly, Reading at the comment is just a mess.